# how to set initial labels in opencv kmeans with KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS

Tags: c++, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

i am using opencv kmeans to cluster points that i get back from convexhull.

in my case i will get 3 points back.
on the next loop through i would like to supply kmeans with those last found 3 points.
i read i have to set KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS.

but how do i set the initial labels/points ?

this is what i have so far, but it returns errors:

```
//get all convexhull points and average them in 3 groups
                    int dimensions = 2;
                    float pointsdata[sampleCount*2]; //[] = {1,1, 2,2, 6,6, 5,5, 10,10};

                    int cnt = 0;
                    for(int a=0; a<sampleCount; a++){
                        pointsdata[cnt] = convexHull[a].x;
                        cnt++;
                        pointsdata[cnt] = convexHull[a].y;
                        cnt++;
                    }

                    cv::Mat points;
                    points = cv::Mat(sampleCount,dimensions, CV_32F,pointsdata);

                    int clusterCount = 3; //i want 3 averaged points back

                    cv::Mat labels;
                    labels = cv::Mat(3,1,points.type());
                    labels.at<float>(0,0) = pointA.x;
                    labels.at<float>(0,1) = pointA.y;

                    labels.at<float>(0,2) = pointB.x;
                    labels.at<float>(0,3) = pointB.y;

                    labels.at<float>(0,4) = pointC.x;
                    labels.at<float>(0,5) = pointC.y;

                    cv::Mat centers;
                    centers = cv::Mat(clusterCount, 1, points.type());



                    kmeans(points, 3, labels, cv::TermCriteria(), 2,cv::KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS, &centers);
```

update:
ok i know now that labels means indices to points in the input cluster, not actual coordinates.
so it should be more like this. but still wrong.

```
cv::Mat labels;
                    labels = cv::Mat(3,1,points.type());
                    labels.at<int>(0,0) = labelA;
                    labels.at<int>(0,1) = labelB;
                    labels.at<int>(0,2) = labelC;
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial cluster assignments need to be of type `CV_32S` not `CV_32F`.  You can see the other conditions in matrix.cpp:

```
CV_Assert( (best_labels.cols == 1 || best_labels.rows == 1) &&
              best_labels.cols*best_labels.rows == N &&
              best_labels.type() == CV_32S &&
              best_labels.isContinuous());
```

The values of your labels should be in the range `[0,N)` where `N` is the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

The labels need to be assigned one per row. So, in your case, they would have to assigned as:

```
cv::Mat labels;
labels = cv::Mat(3,1,points.type());
labels.at<int>(0,0) = labelA;
labels.at<int>(1,0) = labelB;
labels.at<int>(2,0) = labelC;
```

on a side note: your code in the above edit is wrong. You have allocated three rows and are writing to three columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
cv::Mat labels;
labels = cv::Mat(sampleCount,1,CV_32S);
for(int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
    labels.at<int>(i,0) = 0;
labels.at<int>(position1, 0) = 0;
labels.at<int>(position2, 0) = 1;
labels.at<int>(position3, 0) = 2;
```

labels is a 1*N or N*1 integer array that stores the clusterid of each point in the sample. So be sure that

1. the size of labels: 1*N or N*1 (not 1*K or K*1)
2. the type of labels: CV_32S, because it stores clusterid, it should be integer
3. the range of labels: each element in labels is in [0, K)